# How to rebind JQgrid data after applying search on the existing grid data

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I have a customer details where I am showing the customers bill status which is working fine,
Is it possible to rebind the grid once we loaded the data in grid for example:
when I am coming from another page how to apply search on the existing grid data and rebind it to grid.
Below is my colmodel and other properties which I am using but not working properly,

```
 $("#BillDetails").jqGrid({
      url: '../Handler.ashx,
      datatype: "json",
      colNames: [ 'S.No', 'Bill NO', 'Customer Name', 'Customer Type', 'Bill Date',Bill Status'],
      colModel: [
      { name: 'SERIAL', sortable: false, search: true, stype: 'text', width: 40, hidden: false,
               align: 'right', sorttype: 'int' },
      { name: 'BILL_NO', sortable: false, search: true, width: 80, hidden: false, 
               align: 'right',formatter: editLink,},

      { name: 'CUSTOMER_NAME', search: true, align: 'left', width: 150, aligh: 'left', 
               sortable: false },
      { name: 'CHECK_TYPE', align: 'left', width: 150, search: true, aligh: 'left', 
               sortable: false},
      { name: 'BILL_DATE', width: 85, sortable: false, search: true, align: 'center', 
               sorttype: 'date', formatter: "date", formatoptions: { newformat: 'd/m/Y' } },
      { name: 'BILL_STATUS', width: 90, align: 'left', search: true, stype: 'select', 
               searchoptions: { value: 'Pending:Pending;
               On Hold:On Hold;Clear:Clear;Incompelete:InComplete,sortable: false } },
      ],
      width: '980',
      height: '450',
      shrinkToFit: false,
      sortable: true,             
      mtype: 'GET',
      scrollbar: true,
      sortname: 'BILL_NO',
      sortorder: 'asc',
      hidegrid: false,
      loadonce: true,
      ignoreCase: true,
      rowNum: 50,
      pager: '#Pager',
      viewrecords: true,
      // Search on page load from grid data
      gridComplete: function () {
          var searchFilter = "Clear";  // In this I will receive the the status from query string, 
                  //for   now i have provided the the hard core value to test
          var gridData = $("#jQGridDemo").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data');
          console.log(gridData);
          if (searchFilter != "") {
          var grid = $("#BillDetails"), f;
          f = { rules: [] };
          f.rules.push({ field: "STATUS", op: "eq", data: searchFilter });
          grid[0].p.search = true;
          $("#BillDetails").setGridParam({ data: gridData, postData: { filters: f }, 
                    datatype:   "local", });
       }
     }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reload jqGrid when coming from another page with search parameters you could use `postData` property of `jqGrid`.

Something like this:

```
$("#BillDetails").jqGrid({
      url: '../Handler.ashx',
      datatype: "json",
      mtype: 'GET',
      postData:
      {
         Page: 'Dashboard',
         strUserID: strUserID,
      }
```

You can populate this property with js or on server side as you need.

**UPDATE**

You also can use `setGridParam` method of jqgrid:

```
$("#BillDetails").jqGrid('setGridParam', 
{ 
    postData: {
       Page: 'Dashboard',
       strUserID: strUserID,
    }
});
$("#BillDetails").trigger("reloadGrid");
```

But as i understand this way you also just add values to `postData` property.
Also you can try it this way:

```
$("#BillDetails").trigger('reloadGrid', [{page:1}]);
```

You can pass there your new params as on grid init.

Comment: Page and strUserID are used to identity the page request came from because I am using a single a handler for multiple pages. And I want to apply search on client end only on the json data which I received from handler. Thanks

Comment: Well, this approach allowes you to do that. All parameters from `postData` is what you get on server side to get your json for `jqgrid`.

Comment: I tried that but didn't work for me, is there any other method to rebind the grid?

Comment: you can pass parameters right to `url` param, like you already did, other way i mention in the answer.